# is possible to add text as watermark in Crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I want to add dynamic text (that is coming from table) as a watermark using crystal report in visual studio 2019.
If it is possible, please share advice.
Thank You...

Comment: [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to split the Page Header section into PHa and PHb sections (right click PH and select 'Insert Section Below' to split the section).
Make Page Header B section tall.

In the section properties turn on the option to 'Underlay Following Sections'.

Place the Watermark Field/Formula/Parameter in Page Header B and make the font size large and Gray. The image below shows an example.

Note: if you need fancier watermark, such as text orientation that is not limited to 0, 90, 270), there are a couple of other options. But the solution above is the simplest.
[image]